# AngualrJs: do I require $scope in my controller for this?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ag-grid

I am trying to emulate [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/2rCcJN), specifically adding a button to each row of an ag-grid.

```
function ageClicked(age) {
    window.alert("Age clicked: " + age);
}

function ageCellRendererFunc(params) {
    params.$scope.ageClicked = ageClicked;
    return '<button ng-click="ageClicked(data.age)">Age</button>';
}
```

Ag-grid calls `ageCellRendererFunc` to render the cell. It is generating some HTML to ender a button, which, when clicked will cause `ageClicked` to be called.

That `params.$scope.ageClicked = ageClicked;` seems to be assigning a `$scope` variable, which is used in the button code: `'<button ng-click="ageClicked(data.age)">Age</button>'`.

I am not sure whay it is necessary to assigne a `$scope` variable, and why we can't just reference a `$scope` function.  Can that be done?

More to the point, I do not inject `$scope` into my controller, bause I use the `constroller as` syntax in the view.

How can I get a similar piece of code working, adding an HTML button to an `ag-grid` cell, using the `controller as` sytax?

---

[Update] the Plunker referenced above uses a very old version of ag-grid.

1. I want to use the newest version, v22
2. I do not want to use `$scope` or `$rootscope`, just `this` and `controller as` syntax
3. each row should contain one cell which displays a button which, when clicked, executes a function with soem row data as paraemeter (just like the "age" in the Plunker, but fulfilling 1 & 2 in this list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `$scope` inside `ag-grid` (plunker)

Before it calls `ageCellRendererFunc`

```
function ageCellRendererFunc(params) {
    params.$scope.ageClicked = ageClicked;
    eturn '<button ng-click="ageClicked(data.age)">Age</button>';
 }
```

it initializes `params` (4012):

```
RenderedCell.prototype.createParams = function () {
            var params = {
                node: this.node,
                data: this.node.data,
                value: this.value,
                rowIndex: this.rowIndex,
                colDef: this.column.colDef,
                $scope: this.scope, // <----
                context: this.gridOptionsWrapper.getContext(),
                api: this.gridOptionsWrapper.getApi()
            };
            return params;
        };
```

So you can use `controller as`

```
module.controller("exampleCtrl", function($http) {
  var vm = self;
  /* ... */
 }
```

[plunger with vm](http://plnkr.co/edit/41vsiT9D0Bdi08mX)

---

**EDIT 1**

This is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YS6YEATaq0lMFw4L) that uses ag-grid 22.0.0

(Added `agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular)`)

This code is good:

```
function ageCellRendererFunc(params) {
    params.$scope.ageClicked = ageClicked;
    return '<button ng-click="ageClicked(data.age)">Age</button>';
 }
```

As you mentioned `$scope` is related to `params` and not your controller. Your controller does not use `$scope` at all. This is a definition of ag-grid. The developers can use another variable - `bob` and the syntax will be `params.bob.ageClicked = ageClicked;`

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Unfortunately, I am using ag-grid v22.0.0 (and your Plinker uses only v2.3.4), and when I breakpoiint inside of the render function, `params.$scope` is `null`. Is there any way to do it without referring to `$scope`? For instance, could I `function ageCellRendererFunc(params) { vm.ageClicked = ageClicked; return '<button ng-click="vm.ageClicked(data.age)">Age</button>'};?` and update the HTML to use controller as` on the div that contains the grid?

Comment: I still see `params$scope` as `null`. Can it be because you are using the enterprise version of ag-grid and I am using the community version? (thans for helping :-)  Nope, More likely becuase, as you say `$scope: this.scope, // <----` (why no `$` ?) and `this` is undefined in `function ageCellRendererFunc`

Comment: Perhaps it is because my grid is in a state view of ui-router?

Comment: Is terhe any other way to do this? Mayeb a hidden column (or 1px wide), and get the row data when the row is clicked?

Comment: not at all. it is not related to UI. do you have a community url js path? So I can put it into the demo

Comment: I am close to the answer now. It seesm to be because [angularCompileRows must be set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247673/in-ag-grid-what-does-the-option-angularcompilerows-do#comment108516104_38247673) in the gridOptions (see also [this](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/85), question from Nick Ceolter , co-author of ag-grid

Comment: My problem is that I need acces tothe grid's API, see  @Walfrat answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341440/ng-click-not-worked-inside-ag-grid-cell). My problem is that in the `onGridReady ` callback, the API is still not defined. I am looking into adding a delay

Comment: Maxim, there is more to it than I thought - I need my ag-grid to be in the view of a UI-router state. Can you please take a look at [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423793/angularjs-addign-a-button-to-an-ag-grid-cell-in-a-ui-router-state-view)? Thanks

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I see you use old ag-grid 3.3.3, u mentioned 22.0.0, no?

Comment: I guess I based on the wrong Punker, then :-( I will upgrade it. Thanks

Comment: Looks like ag-gris is at v23 now - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/23.0.2/ag-grid-community.min.js

Comment: I added in your other question the plunger for 23, enjoy :)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica you welcome to accept it and vote for other users. thanks