# AngularJs adding a button to an ag-grid cell in a UI-router state view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ag-grid

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61294833/angualrjs-do-i-require-scope-in-my-controller-for-this), about AngularJs and ag-grid, using a cell render to place a button into a cell grid, which, when clicked, does something based on the data.

I got, and accpeted, a great answer from @MaximShoustin, but see now that there is more to it than I thought - I need my ag-grid to be in the view of a UI-router state.

So, I tried to merge [Maxim's Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YS6YEATaq0lMFw4L) with a Plunker of my own, which [shows an ag-grid in a UI-view router state](http://plnkr.co/plunk/JB35OQmljaM2b0qT) and I have made [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JB35OQmljaM2b0qT), which is not working :-(

> angular.js:11598 TypeError: Cannot set property 'priceClicked' of null
>      at priceCellRendererFunc (http://run.plnkr.co/preview/ck9ff1oft00083b63laoskhz3/controllers.js:64:36)

which is because `params.$scope` is `null`.

If I insert a line `params.$scope = [];`, the grid is rendered, but clicking the button does nothing.

What am I doing wrongly? Can anyone help?

I want to

- add a button to an AngularJs ag-grid
- which is in the view of a UI-router state

Hmm, is it necessary to add `angularCompileRows` to the grid options (in additon to the api = null problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with `ag-grid` but suggest you do not afraid to dive into `ag-grid.js` :) .

In your example, you do not provide any `$scope` to `Grid`

```
new agGrid.Grid(theGridDiv, $scope.grid);
```

After opening `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/3.3.3/ag-grid.js` we can see that you can provide `$scope` to `Grid` constructor because in your case `params.$scope = null`

This is a full constructor:

```
Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions, globalEventListener, $scope, $compile, quickFilterOnScope)
```

So I changed it to:

```
new agGrid.Grid(theGridDiv, $scope.grid, null, $scope, $compile, null)
```

---

Next, you need to tell to `ag-grid` to compile your `ng-click` (because `CellRenderer` returns string only):

```
$scope.grid = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    angularCompileRows:true,
   //...
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

<kbd>[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sekE1xCgWz9tXC72)</kbd>

---

**[EDIT 1]**

`ag-grid` v23: <kbd>[Plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/qk6pBtNQXEPj2Riy)</kbd>

Worth to use directive `ag0grid`:

```
<div ag-grid="grid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
```

It takes your scope automatically (from `ag-grid/23.0.2/ag-grid-community.js`):

```
function initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular) {
    var angularModule = angular.module("agGrid", []);
    angularModule.directive("agGrid", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            controller: ['$element', '$scope', '$compile', '$attrs', AngularDirectiveController],
            scope: true
        };
    });
}
```

---

**[EDIT 2]**

<kbd>[plunker without directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/LzQ66KxdxaJOThrs)</kbd>

```
<div id="gridDiv" class="ag-fresh" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
```

Be sure to add `params`:

```
var gridParams = {
        $scope: $scope,
        $compile: $compile
    };

  const theGridDiv = document.querySelector('#gridDiv');
  new agGrid.Grid(theGridDiv, $scope.grid, gridParams);
```